# Parcel bundler cutting of SVG ID form href in <use>

Tags: html, svg, parcel

I've got a problem with Parcel, i was searching for any help but couldn't find one.

When i use Parcel bundler i run into problem with SVG elements

Before:

```
<svg class="nav__icon">
   <use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-edit"></use>
</svg>
```

After:

```
<svg class="nav__icon">
  <use href="/icons.c4b52749.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

Parcel is cutting of ID after # in href URL.

I've tried using this in .htmlnanorc

```
{
"minifySvg": {
    "plugins": [
        { "cleanupIDs": false }
    ]
} }
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<use href="src/img/icons.svg#icon-edit"></use>
```

with

```
<use href="src/img/icons.svg" data-anchor="icon-edit"></use>
```

and finally, change your build script to this (don't forget to replace input and output)

```
parcel build <Your files to build here> && sed -r -i -e 's/(href=\"([^\"]*\\.html)\"([^\"><]*)\\sdata-anchor=\"([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]+)\")/href=\"\\2#\\4\"\\3/g' <Your output path here>/*.html
```

Also, svg elements should have xmlns attribute set up.
Hope it works well.

Sources:

1. [Github/parcel-bundler issue #703](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/703)
2. [Github/parcel-bundler issue #6048](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6048)

Comment: Ive tried this method also, but ran into another problems with it. But i looked into your source links and realised that its the latest update problem, so i downgraded to 2.0.0-beta.1 and for now its working. Will wait untill some fix, i have too many elements to fix and it would be tiring to fix it with this method. Thanks for help anyways

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with SVG icons not being displayed on the index.html file.
The latest version of Parcel download `2.0.0-rc.0` resolves this issue with the caveat that the "main": "index.html" entry needs to be removed from the `package.json` file and type attribute with the value "module" needs to be added to the script tag in index.html.